# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [4, 304]

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

i tried to make a confusion matrix from the model that i make, all seems fine till making the model until i approach a error that says

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of
> samples: [4, 304]

here are the code that i use

```
# Convert List to numpy array, for Keras use
Train_label = np.eye(n_labels)[label] # One-hot encoding by np array function
Train_data = np.array(data)
print("Dataset shape is",Train_data.shape, "(size, timestep, column, row, channel)")
print("Label shape is",Train_label.shape,"(size, label onehot vector)")
# shuffling dataset for input fit function
# if don`t, can`t train model entirely
x = np.arange(Train_label.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(x)
# same order shuffle is needed
Train_label = Train_label[x]
Train_data = Train_data[x]

train_size = 0.9
X_train=Train_data[:int(Totalnb * 0.9),:]
Y_train=Train_label[:int(Totalnb * 0.9)]
X_test=Train_data[int(Totalnb * 0.1):,:]
Y_test=Train_label[int(Totalnb * 0.1):]
# 2. Buliding a Model
# declare input layer for CNN+LSTM architecture
video = Input(shape=(timesteps,img_col,img_row,img_channel))
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = 120
#AlexNet Layer
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    # 1st conv
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(96, (11,11),strides=(4,4), activation='relu', input_shape=(img_col, img_row, img_channel)),
  tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, strides=(2,2)),
    # 2nd conv
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (5,5),strides=(1,1), activation='relu',padding="same"),
  tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, strides=(2,2)),
     # 3rd conv
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(384, (3,3),strides=(1,1), activation='relu',padding="same"),
  tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    # 4th conv
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(384, (3,3),strides=(1,1), activation='relu',padding="same"),
  tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    # 5th Conv
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu',padding="same"),
  tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, strides=(2,2)),
])
model.trainable = True
# FC Dense Layer
x = model.output
x = Flatten()(x)
cnn_out = Dense(128)(x)
# Construct CNN model 
Lstm_inp = Model(model.input, cnn_out)
# Distribute CNN output by timesteps 
encoded_frames = TimeDistributed(Lstm_inp)(video)
# Contruct LSTM model 
encoded_sequence = LSTM(256)(encoded_frames)
hidden_Drop = Dropout(0.2)(encoded_sequence)
hidden_layer = Dense(128)(hidden_Drop)
outputs = Dense(n_labels, activation="softmax")(hidden_layer)
# Contruct CNN+LSTM model 
model = Model([video], outputs)
# 3. Setting up the Model Learning Process
# Model Compile 
opt = SGD(lr=0.01)
model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
# 4. Training the Model
hist = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, validation_split=validation_ratio, shuffle=True, epochs=num_epochs)

Y_pred2 = model.predict(X_test)
y_pred= np.argmax(Y_pred2, axis=1) # prediksi
y_test=np.argmax(Y_test, axis=0)
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred) 
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))
sns.heatmap(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred), annot=True, fmt=".0f", ax=ax)
plt.xlabel("Y_head")
plt.ylabel("Y_true")
plt.show()
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
```

everything seems fine and work but the error come out when i try to make the confussion matrix in the line `confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)`

i still cant figure what might be the problem

hope anyone can help me with this

thank you so much guys

Comment: Could you post the whole error stack, please? One possible thing that looks a bit weird is that you take different axis when calculating the argmax for `y_pred` and `y_test`.  But that might be ok depending on your data layout.

Comment: hi tina, 
i just edited the error problem that i approach, if its depending on my data layout, here are the link of my drive to my dataset, https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1J8tRdYnKu2s7zeuVx6rRT-OeuxWdhfQF?usp=sharing

Comment: but if its depending on my data layout, isnt it should error when i make my model too? because its all fine when i try to compile and fit my model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comments as answer for completeness:

One possible thing that looks a bit weird is that you take different axis when calculating the argmax for `y_pred` and `y_test`. But that might be ok depending on your data layout.

`y_test` and `y_pred` seem be be of different lengths. Can you check the shapes of `Y_pred2` and `Y_test` and see if the axes over which you calculate the argmax are correct.